# Switch case not being entered in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, switch-statement, switching

I'm having a task to solve in which I have to find the biggest sum between the digits of 3nums integer.

I've decided to do it with "switch case", because I am still a newbie.
But, unfortunately when I run it, it skips directly out after the loop.
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        int nums = Integer.parseInt(input);
        int firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum, sumNums, sumNums2 = 0;

        firstNum = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(0));
        secondNum = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(1));
        thirdNum = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(2));

        switch (nums) {
            case 1:
                sumNums = firstNum + secondNum + thirdNum;
                sumNums2 = sumNums;
            case 2:
                sumNums = firstNum + secondNum * thirdNum;
                if (sumNums > sumNums2) {
                    sumNums2 = sumNums;
                }
            case 3:
                sumNums = firstNum * secondNum + thirdNum;
                if (sumNums > sumNums2) {
                    sumNums2 = sumNums;
                }
            case 4:
                sumNums = firstNum * thirdNum + secondNum;
                if (sumNums > sumNums2) {
                    sumNums2 = sumNums;
                }
            case 5:
                sumNums = firstNum * secondNum * thirdNum;
                if (sumNums > sumNums2) {
                    sumNums2 = sumNums;
                    break;
                }
        }
        System.out.println(sumNums2);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What loop? And what number are you entering? No three digit number is going to be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Comment: What input are you giving it when you run it?

Comment: 111, or 257, or any three digit num.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are switching on the variable `nums`, which you are expecting a 3 digit number. Any 3 digit number entered will not match any of your single digit case statements, so it falls out of the switch all together.

It appears that you are intending to have the user first input a singer digit number 1 thru 5 representing an operation to match one of the cases - you never do that.

Also, you should first print out via a `System.out.println()` statement what input you are asking for before scanning for input.

Comment: I see.
Is there any way to make this checks inside the switch?
I want to find the biggest result from the digits.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a switch would make sense in this case. Biggest result from the digits using what formula?

Comment: In you code you have a variable called sumNums but then you use multiplication - not making much sense

Comment: Summing the digits in a 3 digit number is the same in any order. Lets say the number is 543. 5 + 4 + 3 is the same result as 3 + 4 + 5 or 4 + 5 + 3, so what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks odd:

```java
switch (nums) {  // 111, 257  wrong input, no match

// suggest to add default, so you can debug the problem
}
```